# Does Xerox DocuShare support the CMIS protocol?

Tags: cmis, ecm, docushare

Can I access the content of a [DocuShare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_DocuShare) repository using the [CMIS protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services)?

CMIS is a recently-released standard to access ECM repositories. It is already usable with [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) and [Nuxeo](http://www.nuxeo.com/), and many other ECM vendors are implementing it, but I can't find any information for DocuShare.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about features of a Content Management System, not programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently yes, Xerox DocuShare (at least 6.6.1) supports CMIS.

Reference: I have found [this presentation file written by Xerox](https://docushare.xerox.com/partner/dsweb/Get/Version-9200/Docushare%202013%20Presentation.pptx) which contains this graph:

---

[image: Xerox DocuShare CMIS]

---

After talking with a DocuShare expert, it appears that `Xerox Mobile Client for DocuShare` is a CMIS client, so `Mobile Client Connecter` seems to be a DocuShare-to-CMIS gateway.

The CMIS URL has a pattern like this `http://yourserver/<something>/ds_mobile_connector/atom`, with notably the 2 following patterns seen in the wild:

- `http://yourserver/docushare/ds_mobile_connector/atom`
- `http://yourserver/documents/ds_mobile_connector/atom`

Apparently, the CMIS features:

- does not exist in all versions of DocuShare (meaning not on old versions I guess),
- is off by default and has to be enabled manually.